# How to show that a multivariable function is not differentiable?

Tags: calculus

How would I show that $$f(x,y) = \frac{2xy}{x^2 + y^2}$$

is not differentiable at the origin?

Is it enough to show that as the function tends to the origin along the paths $y = x$ and $y=2x$ that we get different limits and hence the function is not continuous?

Comment: How is the function defined at $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}, & (x,y)\ne (0,0)\\0, & (x,y)= (0,0).\end{cases}$$

In this case, look at the limit of $f$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ along the line $y=x$.

Comment: Technically the function could be defined as anything at the origin and it wouldn't ever be differentiable at the origin, in fact not even continuous.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.